# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm trying to create drop down component in my react app.
My react is as follows:

```
 componentDidMount() {
      let initialBrands = [];
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/brands').then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      let brandFromApi = data.map(brand => { return {value: brand, display: brand} })
      this.setState({ brands: [{value: '', display: '(Select your favourite brand)'}].concat(brandFromApi) });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

But when compiling the page it gives the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at App.js:82
```

I can't any other errors other than the above.
However, my dropdown list is not populated.
Anybody, please let me know where is the issue?

Comment: Use the browser's "Network" tool to see what the actual content of the HTTP request is.

Comment: You are probably getting a HTML-formatted error message instead of the JSON you were expecting

Comment: I can only see this error in my console.

Comment: what if you print in console this: `console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));console.log('type of data: ' + typeof data);` before `let brandFromApi = ...`, what does it show?

Comment: Check your App.js code, line 82 as the error says... it will be helpful if you post your whole code but I have the same thoughts as @Bergi

Comment: @c-chavez It never comes to that line, it's `response.json()` that is rejecting the promise

Comment: @chk.buddi then `http://localhost:3000/brands` is not giving you the response, and instead you are getting an error. Does it work in the browser? or using Postman?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're receiving `HTML` (or `XML`) back from the server, but you are trying to parse it as `JSON` which is resulting the error. Also Check the "Network" tab in Chrome dev tools to see contents of the server's response.

Try hitting the URL by browser or postman to check whether you really get a valid `JSON` response.